# How to build a matrix(ndarray) if I have a dictionary telling me the left,right,up,bottom of each item?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

(This is more like a algorithm question tbh)
I want to build a matrix of n*m size.(N,M are something like 130 * 100). I have a dictionary which tells me the left,right,up,down of each element. How do I build a matrix based on that?

```
sampleDictionary = 
{
    (0,0): {'up': (0,1), 'down':None, 'right': (1,0), 'left': None},
    (1,1): {'up': (1,2), 'down': (1,0), 'right': (2,1), 'left': (0,1)}
    # etc......

}

# this is only an example, in the real the items are not tuples but objects so there is no coordinates for them
```

Comment: Can you please provide a sample array and it's corresponding dictionary? The structure of dictionary seems ambiguous.

Comment: I just added a sample dictionary as above

Comment: @XiaowenZhu can you add a minimal complete dictionary, and how exactly you want to populate the matrix ? What does `left` `right` signify ?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a simple loop if I didn't misunderstand you, I think you should complete by yourself.

```
dict = {}
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(M):
        up = (i, j+1) if j<N-1 else None
        down = (i, j-1) if j>0 else None
        left = (i-1, j) if j>0 else None
        right = (i+1, j) if j<M-1 else None
        dict[(i, j)] = {'up':up, 'left':left, 'down':down, 'right':right}
```